# Django CMS plugin custom template

Tags: plugins, django-templates, django-cms

I'm using django-cms 2.2 and imagestore as gallery plugin. But I need to customize galley view. ImageStore uses imagestore_album.html template to render gallery, I created it and put into my tempaltes folder. how I can setup imagestore to use my template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just added cms/plugins/imagestore_album.html and now plugin uses my template, it was too easy